# How to check if a matrix is upper-triangular in clojure

Tags: vector, matrix, clojure

I want to write a function to compute upper triangular nature of matrix. So lets say a_i_j be the number in the i^th row and j^th column. A matrix is 
upper-triangular if a_i_j = 0 for all i > j.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(defn is-upper-triangular [m]
  (->> (map-indexed vector m)
       (mapcat (fn [[r v]] (take r v)))
       (every? zero?)))
```

The above code take 0 element from the first row, 1 element from the second row, and 2 elements from the third rows, etc... and checks that all the taken elements are zero. If all are zero, it is upper triangular.

This code does not check that the given matrix is square. You can add this check if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`upper-triangular?` isn't in the `core.matrix` API yet, but if you use `vectorz-clj` you can get at the function with Java interop:

```
(def a (array :vectorz [[1 2] [0 4]]))

(.isUpperTriangular a)
=> true

(.isUpperTriangular (transpose a))
=> false
```

Comment: (def a (array :vectorz [[1 2] [0 4]])) gives following exception. I am using Leiningen on windows. CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: array in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:8)

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a `(use 'clojure.core.matrix)` first to import the core.matrix API functions into your current namespace